# Deploy admin interface on a different port

Tags: django, apache, deployment, virtualhost

Is it possible in django/apache to deploy parts of the django app in one way, and parts in the other. For example, lets say I have my interface for regular users, on www.coolsite.com, but I want to give access to the admin view on www.coolsite.com:1234. Is that doable within a single app?

Also, is it possible to deploy two different django apps differently (lets say I want to have a "web" app on port 80, and an "api" app on port 8888)?

I know I can move the apps into different *projects* but I would not split them unless I have to (they share settings and models)

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *sort of* answers your question.

Most of the time I use a 3 server setup — dev, staging, production — but sometimes I *must* do the debug in the production directory (although I really hate doing that). When I do that I often run the Django dev server at 8000 (or whatever) and connect to that.

I have a bunch of debug stuff that only prints out if the port is in 8000..8002. Technically I'm running a completely different server, but it's using all of the same settings/DB/code as production. I simply set a DEBUG_PRINT value in `settings.py` that tests for the appropriate port range.

Does this sound like it would meet your need?

**Update:**

In `settings.py` you can have something like this:

```
ALLOW_ADMIN = '800' in HOST_PORT
```

and then in `urls.py` you can do something like this:

```
if settings.ALLOW_ADMIN:
    urlpatterns += patterns((r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)))
else:
    urlpatterns += patterns((r'^admin/.*', 'views.no_admin'))
```

And then you can yell at them in views.no_admin, or give them a link to the other server.

Comment: Well, running a separate server/instance on the other may be a solution, but I would have to figure out how to block admin request on one port and not the other. I am not talking about debug, though, but ongoing maintenance. I would want to give admin access my clients' IT staff.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach that doesn't require multiple processes/projects. Add a middleware component like this:

```
class ProtectAdminMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.path.startswith("/admin") and request.META["SERVER_PORT"] != "1234":
            raise Http404
```

Answer (score 1):

One easy way I can think of off the top of my head is sort of a spin on the idea of multiple projects. If your code is in a source versioning system (and why wouldn't it be?), then you can easily create separate pulls of the same branch or tag and serve each in a different way, i.e. one over port 80, one over port 8000, one on a completely different domain, etc.

The only thing you would need to do is create pull-specific urls.py (meaning you would ignore it in your source versioning system) or perhaps find a way to use something like a local_urls.py (never tried it myself). In each version, you can turn on/off the urlpatterns you do or don't want in that particular environment. Only want the admin on port 8000? Only put that urlpattern in the pull being served at port 8000.